# The true nature of division in light of Euclid's understanding of multiplication

Tags: arithmetic

I'm not a math major, but a philosophy major that likes to know that he knows what he's talking about. This may seem like a super stupid question, but here I go.

So Euclid made a lot of sense when he gave the example of the nature of multiplication. For example.
"2 x 3" is really 2 added to itself 3 times, and vice versa, and this is different from 2 + 3, which is five, two units added to three.

But, what about division?

It seems to be the opposite of multiplication like a mirror image from 3rd grade, but I'm starting to doubt that after digging deeper.

For example, [this site](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/dictionary/D-words/definition-of-divide.php) gave the following diagram for division: [image]

Based on this image, for 6/3, division seems to be the counting of groups, not the inverse of multiplication according to Euclid.

Can someone explain the true nature of division in light of the euclid example I gave?

Comment: The "true nature of division" depends on the context and may have different explanations. I suggest, you ponder the fraction $3/6$, or better, $\pi/e$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: There is an old book by Harold D. Larsen, published in 1950, called ARITHMETIC FOR COLLEGES$. It's a practical survey of present and historical methods of doing arithmetic.  There is a lot any student of mathematics could learn from it.

Comment: Thank you Steven Gregory. I ordered it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One really should not currently consider Euclid's as an authoritative treatment of mathematics (2300 or so years since his "Elements" were written). Even his axiomatic development of geometry was faulty, as it was realized in 19th century. Still, one can use "Elements" when teaching axiomatic geometry these days.

It is worse with arithmetic/algebra. Euclid's notion of "numbers" is very limited. (Only natural numbers were considered as "proper" numbers and, even 1 was not uniformly regarded as a number.) Explaining division as "counting in groups" if you want to explain the concept to an 8 year old child is fine (as long as you limit the discussion to the case when the outcome of the division is a natural number). But once you learn about negative integers, rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, you realize that "counting in groups" looses any meaning. If you follow the axiomatic treatment of, say, real numbers, you realize that the only meaningful definition of division is
$$
\frac{a}{b}= a\cdot b^{-1},
$$
(for $b\ne 0$) where $b^{-1}$ is defined as the unique real number such that $b\cdot b^{-1}=1$.  (The existence of $b^{-1}$ is one of the axioms.) You can also say that
$$
\frac{a}{b}=c \iff a= bc,
$$
hence, division appears as the inverse to the multiplication function when $a$ is chosen in advance and $b, c$ are the variables.

The same definition of division applies to more general algebraic structures called **[fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).** There are more general algebraic structures where division is defined, called **division rings**, but one then has to distinguish between $ab^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}a$.

Answer (score 0):

E.g., $6:3 = 2$ is the number of blocks of length 3 that fit into a block of 6.

Similarly, $7:3$ is the number of blocks of length 3, namely 2, that fit into a block of length 7, with a residue block of 1:

$7 = 2\cdot 3 + 1$ (division with remainder).

Comment: So if 2 when 6 is divided by 3 is the value that represents 2 blocks with the total length of 3, then you're saying that multiplication is a block with the length of 3 added to itself two times. So does this mean that a block with the length of 2 added to itself 3 times is the inverse 6/2?

Comment: Basically, what I meant in the previous comment is that the operations of multiplication and division have connected pairs like 2 x 3 = 6 is the opposite of 6/2 = 3 and 3 x 2 = 6 is the opposite of 6/3 = 2?